# Spirit: Fusion doesn't know how to deal with std::pair

Tags: c++, parsing, boost

I'm trying to make a JSON parser but my object rule doesn't compile...

Code (complete code [here](https://github.com/Ardakaniz/JSON-Spirit)):

```
// AST
using Object = std::map<std::string, struct Value>; // (Value is a variant which can contain a float, a string, an Object or an Array)

// Grammar def
using ObjectType = x3::rule<struct ObjectClass, Object>;
const ObjectType obj{"object"};
const auto obj_def = '{' > ((quotedString > ':' > val) % ',') > '}';
```

Error (complete error [here](http://pastebin.com/N5P3ss1P)):

```
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/support/traits/container_traits.hpp:77:56: error: no type named 'value_type' in 'std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, Json::Value>'
  : detail::remove_value_const<typename Container::value_type>
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

The type `std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, Json::Value>` is good, but it must be an array (`std::vector<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, Json::Value>>`, so `std::map<std::basic_string<char>, Json::Value>`)

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your diagnosis is off the mark. You can just eliminate rules and defs until you find the culprit. The `obj_def` is the culprit, which you can confirm by commenting it out:

```
const auto obj_def = x3::eps; // '{' > ((quotedString > ':' > val) % ',') > '}';
```

In your grammardef.hpp you need to include

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
```

so that Fusion knows how to deal with `std::pair<std::string, Json::Value>`.

This is a FAQ entry since early days of Spirit V2 (http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/parsing-a-list-of-key-value-pairs-using-spirit-qi/).

Also, bear in mind that some implementations will expect properties to be ordered (this is not actually specified) and you might want to check against duplicate keys (especially after normalizing unicode escapes).

Comment: I can't try until Wednesday. I removed the rules and defs to find the bad rules as you said, I haven't specified it before. And how could I check duplicate keys?

Comment: I was responding to "Spirit don't convert array to vector". I don't know what that was if it wasn't meant to describe (diagnose) the problem :)
Don't check for duplicate keys. Just store them (`multimap`). /Then/ you're free to do with it what you want (ignore dups, count them, or what not).

Comment: Ah, yeah, the title isn't very explicit, sorry. Fixed! I wouldn't thought to use a multimap, thanks.